# CSS: border not displaying properly

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a vertical left border across several elements and I've tried following a few of the top rated suggestions from [this thread](http://www.example.com/), but to no success.

Currently, the border looks like this:

[image]
(yes, it's that pathetic black line)

Of course, what I actually want is for the line to take up the whole left-hand side of the page. All advice is super appreciated!

My ERB file:

```
<h1 class="p1_vs_p2"><%= @game.player.name %> vs <%=@game.computer.name %></h2>
<h2 class="player_chose"> You chose <%= @game.player.weapon.capitalize %></h2>
<h2 class="computer_chose"><%= @game.computer.name %> chose <%=@game.computer.weapon.capitalize %></h2>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<% if @game.outcome == Game::POSSIBLE_OUTCOMES[0] %>
     <h2 class="victory_message"> Congratulations, you win!</h2>
<% elsif @game.outcome == Game::POSSIBLE_OUTCOMES[1] %>
     <h2 class="tie_message"> It's a tie!</h2>
<% else %>
     <h2 class="defeat_message">You lost this time.</h2>
<% end %>

<h4> <a href="/" class="play_again">Play Again</a> </h4>
<div class="vertical_line">
```

My CSS file:

```
html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  background-color: #f4f1ec;
}

input[type="radio"]{
  margin: 0 5px 0 10px;
}

table.center {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    }

 .title {
   padding-top: 40px;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
   color: #6495ED;
   padding-bottom: 100px;
 }

.input_name_button {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.play_button {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.p1_vs_p2 {
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #B0C4DE;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.player_chose {
  color: #6495ED;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 200px;
}


.computer_chose {
  color: #FFA07A;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.victory_message {
  color: #8FBC8F;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  position: fixed;
}

.tie_message {
  color: #FFDEAD;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  position: fixed;
}

.defeat_message {
  color: #F08080;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  position: fixed;
}

a.play_again {
  color: #A9A9A9;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.vertical_line {
  width: 4px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else and I'll be happy to provide it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to put all content in a div and make it's border properties like this?

> ```
> border-top-style: none;
> border-right-style: none;
> border-bottom-style: none;
> border-left-style: solid;
> ```

Comment: I just tried wrapping all content for the page inside a div and applied the styling you provided, but it just made a slightly bigger black line appear at the top of the page instead? I'm somewhat of a noob when it comes to CSS haha, so forgive me! Oh, and thanks for the reply!

Comment: i just needed to help you .. i tried it on w3shools and it worked well :P

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following CSS to your stylesheet:

```
body {
  margin-left: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
}
```

You also may have to remove a bunch of margins that your headings create.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply. This worked for the most part, but it left a slight gap at both the top and bottom of the page. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably have some elements that have margins, like h1s and such. You will have to reset those margins by giving them a value of `0`.

Comment: Hmm, I have only used 'margin' inside of my CSS file, when referring to classes located on different pages. Could this still be the issue?

Comment: @IainK The margins are created by the browser, so you would have to reset those margins created by the browser inside your own stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the relevant part of the CSS in a div and apply the left border to that DIV

Here's what that results in with your code (not taking into account the scripts you haven't posted, which is the reason for all that "%" stuff in the content):

```css
html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  background-color: #f4f1ec;
}

input[type="radio"]{
  margin: 0 5px 0 10px;
}

table.center {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    }

 .title {
   padding-top: 40px;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
   color: #6495ED;
   padding-bottom: 100px;
 }

.input_name_button {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.play_button {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.p1_vs_p2 {
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #B0C4DE;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.player_chose {
  color: #6495ED;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 200px;
}


.computer_chose {
  color: #FFA07A;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.victory_message {
  color: #8FBC8F;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  position: fixed;
}

.tie_message {
  color: #FFDEAD;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  position: fixed;
}

.defeat_message {
  color: #F08080;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  position: fixed;
}

a.play_again {
  color: #A9A9A9;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper_for_left_border {
  border-left: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper_for_left_border">
<h1 class="p1_vs_p2"><%= @game.player.name %> vs <%=@game.computer.name %></h2>
<h2 class="player_chose"> You chose <%= @game.player.weapon.capitalize %></h2>
<h2 class="computer_chose"><%= @game.computer.name %> chose <%=@game.computer.weapon.capitalize %></h2>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<% if @game.outcome == Game::POSSIBLE_OUTCOMES[0] %>
     <h2 class="victory_message"> Congratulations, you win!</h2>
<% elsif @game.outcome == Game::POSSIBLE_OUTCOMES[1] %>
     <h2 class="tie_message"> It's a tie!</h2>
<% else %>
     <h2 class="defeat_message">You lost this time.</h2>
<% end %>

<h4> <a href="/" class="play_again">Play Again</a> </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, I've tried doing this, but depending on where I start the div, the vertical line only ever takes up a small segment of the page. Unless I've completely misunderstood you, then apologies!

Comment: look at the snippet I added

Comment: Hey Johannes -- thanks for taking the time to include a snippet. Unfortunately, I have already tried this (and I've just tried again using the exact CSS you used), and all this does is move the black line from the middle of the page to the top of the page. Any ideas as to why this might be happening? Thanks again!